# Serialize boost ptime with custom format

Tags: c++, boost, time, format, posix

I have to serialize to a string a `boost::posix_time::ptime` variable. The format I want is this: `2014-05-12T16:14:01.809+0200`. I can't change it because it is requested from a web service and I must comply the format requested.
I can imply that the timezone is the local one.
I saw some examples but I have not found anything that makes me get a `std::string` from an UTC ptime.

Added some details about what I want:
I start from a `boost::posix_time::ptime`. I want to print it in the format I specified before but I don't know what is my real time zone. I have to find it through a library function call.
Then what I have to do is to write a function with this prototype: `std::string time_to_custom_string(boost::posix_time::ptime datetime);`

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind some trailing `000` with the fractional seconds:

```
#include <boost/date_time/local_time/local_time.hpp>
#include <locale>

static boost::local_time::time_zone_ptr const s_timezone(new boost::local_time::posix_time_zone("+02:00"));

std::string mydateformat(boost::local_time::local_date_time const& ldt)
{
    using namespace boost;
    std::ostringstream ss;

    boost::local_time::local_time_facet* output_facet = new boost::local_time::local_time_facet();
    ss.imbue(std::locale(std::locale::classic(), output_facet));
    output_facet->format("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%s%q");

    ss.str("");
    ss << ldt;
    return ss.str();
}

std::string mydateformat()
{
    using namespace boost;

    posix_time::ptime my_ptime = posix_time::second_clock::universal_time();
    local_time::local_date_time ldt(my_ptime, s_timezone);

    return mydateformat(ldt);
}

int main()
{
    using namespace boost;

    gregorian::date d(2014, 5, 12);
    posix_time::time_duration td(16, 14, 1, 809000);
    local_time::local_date_time ldt(d, td, s_timezone, false/*daylight savings*/);

    std::cout << mydateformat(ldt) << "\n";
    assert("2014-05-12T16:14:01.809000+0200" == mydateformat(ldt));
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it isn't what I really want but can be my fault explaining what I want. It can help me through find the real solution. I update my question with more details.

Comment: @user3807511 the way to get a `local_date_time` from a `ptime` is already shown (in the second overload of `mydateformat`!). To convert with "system timezone" see the documentation. Beware, however, that trusting the system timezone may constitute a security vulnerability.

Comment: Can you explain why `utc_time_zone` is initialised from an expression containing the string `"+02:00"`?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Ah. No. Obvious oversight :)

Comment: Incidentally, in a nice twist, I found this because I needed it, not because I was "moderating" SO answers :)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I assumed as much. I sometimes grep my own SO answers for the relevant bits myself :) Faster than going to bitbucket